# Match string in excel cell and write specific value to new/adjacent cell Python

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to match a string in a cell and if it is present I should be able to write a specific string in new cell/column. For example:

**This is my xlsx file:**

```
|UserPrincipalName         |Contact |Age    |Container                           |
|:-------------------------|:------:|:-----:|:--------------------------:|
|John.doe                  |Email   |23     |\Location\EMEA\France\User |
|Jane.doe                  |Phone   |25     |\Location\EMEA\Germany\User|
|Jane12                    |Phone   |25     |\Location\EMEA\Italy\User  |
|Jane1322                  |Phone   |25     |\Location\EMEA\Belgium\User|
|Feng.Main                 |SMS     |21     |\Location\APAC\China\User  |
|serviceaccount            |Email   |       |\Location\Service Accounts |
```

**Expected Output:**

```
|UserPrincipalName         |Contact |Age    |Container                           |Region         |
|:-------------------------|:------:|:-----:|:-----------------:|:--------------|
|John.doe                  |Email   |23     |\Location\EMEA\France\User |EMEA North     |
|Jane.doe                  |Phone   |25     |\Location\EMEA\Belgium\User|EMEA South     |
|Jane12                    |Phone   |25     |\Location\EMEA\Germany\User|EMEA South     |
|Jane1322                  |Phone   |25     |\Location\EMEA\Italy\User  |EMEA North     |
|Feng.Main                 |SMS     |21     |\Location\APAC\China\User  |APAC           |
|serviceaccount            |Email   |       |\Location\Service Accounts |Service Account|
```

**My Code:**

```
  df = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\OpTest.xlsx')
  df['Region'] = df[df['Container'].str.contains(r'\\EMEA\\')]
  df = df.to_excel('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\MFAOpTest.xlsx')
```

My Output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xURSU.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way would be -

```
df = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\OpTest.xlsx')

def myfunc(x):
    if ('EMEA\France' in x or 'EMEA\Italy'in x):
        return "EMEA North"
    elif ('EMEA\Belgium' in x or '\EMEA\Germany' in x):
        return "EMEA South"
    elif 'APAC\China' in x:
        return "APAC"
    elif 'Service Accounts' in x:
        return "Service Account"

df['Region'] = df['Container'].apply(myfunc)
print(df)

df.to_excel('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\MFAOpTest.xlsx')
```

This will add the Region column in DataFrame as expected.
Also, you can customize the function as per your requirements

Comment: @IntelVenus  - If above answer solves your issue, kindly Accept the Answer, so it will be considered as resolved.
If Answer doesn't resolve the issue, please specify the issue

Comment: I tried this and it didnt write anything to the excel file (Command to write the output to excel was added from my end). 
I also tried printing the output and it returned NONE in the Region column when the output was printed.
Will this function match the entire string or check for substring?

Comment: @IntelVenus - I have modified the answer, Please try it again.
There was a syntax error in the code to export the file to EXCEL, hence it was showing output as None. Please check the last line code in my Answer above.
This function will check for substring (not entire string)

Comment: I tried writing this to excel file already. Didnt work :( Also, it still prints NONE in Region. Tried your latest code it also gives the same output.

Comment: @IntelVenus -  Ok, I think there is some misunderstanding about the question.
Can please share the exact steps that you are following ? (So I can try the same on my side) 
Please mention which IDE you are using (Ex - Jupyter notebook, PyCharm etc)
Also, please share the sample EXCEL file (using Website link or Google Drive link)

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for not being active here.
I found the solution for my question.

#Importing the file in which the changes mst be done
import_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(("Excel files", "*.xlsx"),("All files", "*.xlsx") ))
df = pd.read_excel (import_file_path)

#Under the 'Container' column if the string contains 'France' then the 'Region' column must be written with the value EMEA North
df.loc[df['Container'].astype(str).str.contains("France"), 'Region'] = 'EMEA North'
df.loc[df['Container'].astype(str).str.contains("Germany"), 'Region'] = 'EMEA South'

This worked for me!
Appreciate your help Vinay :)

Comment: Just a detail: You could format your text with [code][/code] to help other readers :-)